# Wordpress Pagination: WP-PageNavi and Permalinks doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, pagination, permalinks

I have a clean installation of latest Wordpress version on my local webserver. 
Twenty Twelve Theme by default and WP-Pagenavi plugin installed for Numeric pagination.

I set permalinks for my categories and postslike this:

`http://wordpress352ru/%category%/%postname%/`

Now I can access category "shows" archive with link `http://wordpress352ru/shows/`

Pagination links on that page now look like:

`http://wordpress352ru/shows/page/2/` and it doesn't work.

If I open index page and then click on category shows link then pagination links on shows category page look like this:

`http://wordpress352ru/category/shows/page/2/` and it works.

But I'd like to pagination links would look like this instead and worked:

`http://wordpress352ru/shows/page/2/`

Without word "category" in the link. How can I set this to work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins out there for this, but here is one very easy way of doing it: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-remove-category-from-your-wordpress-url

**EDIT**

Once you've done the above, your pagination should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about plugin! It worked for me! Thought, I still would like to know how to change it manually and prefer not to use plugins when it's possible.

Comment: Would be grateful if you could mark the answer as correct! ;)

Well, this approach isn't a plugin, it's just a tweak to the way the permalinks work. You can also do it via functions.php but however you do it, it's a modification to how WordPress does things as standard.

Comment: Sure, Jack! :) If you have Facebook account I'd be glad to discuss some Wordpress things with you from time to time!